# Will closing my bank account cause my credit card to also close?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I've been with Comerica for many years now. I opened up a credit card with them about  4 years ago. It's my only credit card. I opened up the account to help build credit; it's in good standings and I've never been late on a payment.

I no longer use the bank account that I initially opened up, and I'm now being charged $18/month to keep it opened. There's not much money left in it, so I'm wanting to close it. My concern is that if I close the bank account they will also close out my credit card. **Is it a fairly common occurrence for credit cards to be closed when you close out your other accounts at a bank?**

I can not easily find the original paperwork that came with my credit card, so I wasn't able to read through the fine print. The card issuer is Elan Financial Services.

Comment: Did you open the bank account separate from the card account? If not, are you sure it isn't actually a debit card?

Comment: Have you asked the bank if you can close the savings account but keep the credit card account?  Normally this is not a problem.

Comment: @Nosjack yes it's definitely a credit card. I have a separate portal and a minimum balance I have to pay.

Comment: What is "the" bank account? The credit card is one account; a checking account would be another, savings a third, etc. A credit card isn't a feature of another account. That said, why not ask the bank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not usually, no.

However, sometimes the interest rate on your card is linked to your overall relationship
with the bank (you get a better rate for having more and bigger accounts with them). Hopefully you're not carrying a balance, so this shouldn't be an issue for you.

It's possible the terms and conditions of your credit card agreement require you to keep another account open with the bank. Since you no longer have the T&Cs, you should call the credit card department (not the bank account department!) and ask.